# Count-process datasets for Non-proportional Hazard (Cox) models with interaction variables

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression, survival

I am trying to run a nonproportional cox regression model featuring an interaction-with-time variable, as described in Chapter 15 (section 15.3) of *Applied Longitudinal Data Analaysis* by Singer and Willett. However I cannot seem to get answers that agree with the book.

The data used in this book and source code is supplied at this [fantastic website](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/examples/alda/). Unfortunarely no R code is supplied for the final chapter and the supplied dataset for R for the example discussed in-text is incomplete and provides incorrect answers for the simplest model (which I *do* know how to run). Instead, to obtain the complete dataset for this example, one must click the 'Download' link in the 'SAS' column (which has the correct dataset) and then, after installing the `haven` package (which allows one to read in foreign data formats), read in the dataset in question via:

`haven::read_sas("alda/lengthofstay.sas7bdat")`

This dataset indicates participants' (variable `ID`) length of stay (variable `DAYS`) in inpatient treatment in a hospital. The censoring variable is `CENSOR`. The researchers hypothesised that two different types of treatment (binary variable `TREAT`) would predict differential values of hazard of checking out of treatment. In addition they anticipated that the between-group difference in hazard would *not* be constant over time, therefore requiring the creation of an interaction term. I can get the simple main effect model to work, returning the same hazard coefficients reported in the book (which is how i eventually found out the .csv file supplied with the R code was incomplete).

`summary(modA <- coxph(Surv(DAYS,1-CENSOR) ~ TREAT, data = los))`

```
        coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z Pr(>|z|)
TREAT 0.1457    1.1568   0.1541 0.945    0.345
```

I tried to follow the procedure laid out [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112555/what-s-wrong-with-this-way-of-fitting-time-dependent-coefficients-in-a-cox-regre), and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90218/how-to-create-a-covariate-%C3%97-time-interaction-term-in-cox-regression?noredirect=1&lq=1), and the sources listed therein (e.g. Therneau vignette on time-varying covariates in the `survival` package), and, of course, when I am copy-pasting someone else's code and running that it all works fine. But I am trying to do this for myself from scratch with a dataset whose results I can compare against mine. And I just can't make it work.

first I created an EVENT variable

`los$EVENT <- 1 - los$CENSOR`

there is a duplicate id number in the dataset that causes issues. So we have to change it to a new ID number

`los$ID[which(duplicated(los$ID))] <- 842`

Now, based on what I read [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) and [here](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v061c01/v61c01.pdf.)  the dataframe needs to be split so that, for every participant, there is one row indicating the `EVENT` status at every point prior to their event (or censorship) time when any *other* participant experienced an event. Therefore we need to create a vector of all the unique event times, then split the dataset on those event times

```
cutPoints <- sort(unique(los$DAYS[los$EVENT == 1]))

# now split the dataset
longLOS <- survSplit(Surv(DAYS,EVENT)~ ., data = los, cut = cutPoints) 

# and (just because I'm anal) rename the interval upper bound column (formerly "DAYS")
names(longLOS)[5] <- "tstop"
```

When I looked at this dataset it appeared to be what I was after, with (1) as many rows for each participant as there are intervals prior to their event time when anyone else in the dataset experienced an event, (2) two columns indicating the lower and upper bounds of each interval, and (3) an event column with a 0 for all rows when the respondent did not experience the event, and a 1 in the final row when they either did experience the event or were censored.

Next I created the interaction-with-time variable, subtracting 1 from the 'interval upper bound' column so that main effect of `TREAT` represents the treatment effect on the first day of hospitalisation.

```
longLOS$TREATINT <- longLOS$EVENT*(longLOS$tstop - 1)
```

And ran the model

```
summary(modB <- coxph(Surv(tstart, tstop, EVENT) ~ TREAT + TREATINT, data = longLOS))
```

But it doesn't work! I got the (fairly unhelpful) error message

```
Error in fitter(X, Y, strats, offset, init, control, weights = weights,  : 
  routine failed due to numeric overflow.This should never happen.  Please contact the author.
```

What am I doing wrong? I have been slowly working through Singer and Willett for almost three years (I started while still a grad student), and now the final chapter is proving to be by far my greatest challenge. I have thirty pages to go; any help would be incredibly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. A stupid error when I created the interaction variable `TREATINT`. instead of

`longLOS$TREATINT <- longLOS$EVENT*(longLOS$tstop - 1)`

it should have been

`longLOS$TREATINT <- longLOS$TREAT*(longLOS$tstop - 1)`

Now when you run the model

`summary(modB <- coxph(Surv(tstart, tstop, EVENT) ~ TREAT + TREATINT, data = longLOS))`

Not only does it work, it yields coefficients that match those reported in the Singer and Willett book.

```
              coef exp(coef)  se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)
TREAT     0.706411  2.026705  0.292404  2.416   0.0157
TREATINT -0.020833  0.979383  0.009207 -2.263   0.0237
```

Given how dumb my mistake was I was tempted to just delete this whole post but I think I'll leave it up for others like me who want to know how to do interaction with time Cox models in R.